# Cypress Error Catching: how to catch error, warn using cy.log(), then continue with test

Tags: javascript, performance, cypress, e2e-testing, e2e

so I'm trying to use something like "error catching" to catch an error, `cy.log` a custom error message, then continue with the test without error catching after that point.

For example, clicking a button that increases quantity in cart, then asserting a change in the quantity #.

- If the quantity # doesn't update within 2 seconds, warn in console.
- If the quantity # doesn't update 6 seconds later (for 8 second global default timeout), fail test step

```
//some sort of error catching here which suppresses the error, and cy.logs 

cy.get("#AddToCart").click()
cy.get("#cart-count", timeout: 2000).should(contain, 2)

//disable error catching here

cy.get("#cart-count", timeout: 6000).should(contain, 2)
```

I tried something like

```
cy.on("error", (err, runnable) => {
          expect(err.message).to.include("blue");
          cy.log("this single test failed, but continue other tests");
          return false;
        });
        cy.get(".cy-prc")
          .should("be.visible")
          .invoke("text")
          .should("include", "blue");
```

Where the `.should("include", "blue")` should fail. If I can get this to fail and cy.log, then find a way to disable the error catch and do the 2nd assertion, I think I could get this working as I'm hoping it to.

*Edit: We're trying to measure potential performance issues within a certain threshold, and have a custom warning printed to console when a threshold is exceeded without failing the test. We have several components or elements that can be affected by small changes in the backend, and we'd like to have warnings when we're approaching an unacceptable threshold before they become failing criteria.*

Comment: I think knowing your reasoning for adding a 'error catching' within 2 seconds and then for 6 seconds would help us know what the best approach may be.

Comment: @jjhelguero we're trying to measure potential performance issues within a certain threshold, and have a custom warning printed to console when a threshold is exceeded without failing the test. We have several components or elements that can be affected by small changes in the backend, and we'd like to have warnings when we're approaching an unacceptable threshold before they become failing criteria.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of `command:` events that might be useful

```js
const commands = []

function commandStart(cmd) {
  const id = cmd.attributes.id
  commands.push({
    ...cmd.attributes,
    started: +new Date(),
  })
}

function commandEnd(cmd) {
  const entry = commands.filter(c => c.id === cmd.attributes.id)[0]
  entry.ended = +new Date()
  entry.duration = entry.ended - entry.started
}

Cypress.on('command:start', commandStart)
Cypress.on('command:end', commandEnd)

cy.get("#AddToCart").click()
cy.get("#cart-count", timeout: 2000).should(contain, 2)
```

The commands will look like

[image]

so to check the 2nd command

```js
cy.then(() => {
  cy.wrap(commands[1])
    .its('duration')
    .should('be.lt', 6000)

  // turn off command duration
  Cypress.off('command:start', commandStart)
  Cypress.off('command:end', commandEnd)
})
```